# How to serve one page website via Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Lets say I have developed **one page** application at `example.com/index.html`. How can I serve this file no matter what `example.com/blabla` is the URI. The requested URI should be preserved hence redirection is not an option.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=302]
```

Also setting it as an 404 document can apparently do the job but it is not the positive way.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

*In my case it is custom one page application made with `window.history.pushState` but I am looking for proper way that is used for `Angular.JS` and `Backbone.JS` applications*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one rule would be enough in site root/.htaccess; use `FallbackResource`:

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Comment: on Wamp .htaccess file with these 2 lines is giving 500 error

Comment: I am sorry but still 500. I have `AllowOverride all` in config but still error.

Comment: E:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: ok `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'` means `mod_rewrite` is not enabled in your Apache comfig.

Comment: ok see my updated rule and try `FallbackResource /index.html` instead of above snippet.